# How do I switch from disabled window to frame in selenium?

Tags: selenium, frame, switching

I am switching from *parent window* to *child window*.

Then in the child window, I need to enter login details. Which opens a **frame** and then this child window will be closed.

Now the parent window is in disable state, which is not allowing me to switch to the **frame**?

How Can I handle this scenario, Can someone could help me out?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by 'which opens a frame'? Is that a div or iframe or window?
2. What do you mean by 'Now the parent window is in disable state'?
3. Can you show screenshot or share URL of the app?

Comment: Hi, I am supposed to not to share the URL and screenshot so if possible let me know the solution.
frame means iframe only,